# how can i import useNavigate in a handler file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have a separate file with all my functions but when i try to import my librery react-router-dom and use useNavigate i get errors like

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

or
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #321;`

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';


const navigate = useNavigate();

const onSubmit = async () => {
  navigate('/success');
};

export default {onSubmit};
```

i tried to declare the variable inside the function but i got error

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

    const onSubmit = async () => {

     const navigate = useNavigate();

      navigate('/success');
    };
```

Comment: you're breaking the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You cannot use use hooks outside components. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Instead, you can create `useOnSubmit` hook which you can then use in component body if you want

```js
const useOnSubmit = (cb = () => {}) => {
   const navigate = useNavigate(); 

   const onSubmit = async () => {
      await cb();
      navigate('/success');
   }
   
   return onSubmit;
}
```

Now you can use this hook like the following

```js
const SampleComponent = () => {
   const onSubmit = useOnSubmit(() => {
      // do submit logic here
   });

   return <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: you can't call an undefined value so this will throw an error if `cb` is undefined which it is in your implementation

Comment: @Undo Thanks. I have updated the answer. Let us know if you have better alternatives

Comment: Code will still throw an error if `cb` is not a function, e.g. undefined or string, number, etc.